# App crashes when trying to use camera in Android App / Andoid studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, camera

I'm doing a meal tracker app, where you can track what you eat and also upload images of your  meals to be stored on your phone and then used in the app to display your past meals.

I'm currently trying to add the camera/upload image functionality and I was following along to a tutorial I found on YouTube, however, the app keeps crashing as soon as the "tap to add photo"-Button is clicked.

This is the code inside the "TrackFragment" (where you enter the data for one meal):

```
(...)
public class TrackFragment extends Fragment{

    final int CAMERA_REQ_CODE = 100;
    ImageView imgCamera;

    private final Context trackFragmentContext = this.getContext();

(...)

    
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        // TODO handling camera input to upload image
        imgCamera = view.findViewById(R.id.imgCamera);
        Button btnCamera = view.findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);

        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // start intent (one of these causes crash)
                Intent iCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(iCamera, CAMERA_REQ_CODE);
            }
        });

    }

    // show photo on track fragment below button
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQ_CODE){
                Bitmap img = (Bitmap) (data.getExtras().get("data"));
                imgCamera.setImageBitmap(img);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to the log it seems to be an issue regarding security because of the camera access, however I did include in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I know some of the methods are deprecated but I couldn't find any other tutorials on how to do this.[screenshot of the track-fragment / general UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgnp1.jpg)
Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Remove the `CAMERA` permission. You only need that if you are working with the camera APIs directly. If you continue to crash after that, please edit your question to provide the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, Just disable your CAMERA permissions in your manifest and you are good.